# Captiva problem

Tags: electrical, performance, captiva

My Captiva Diesel 2007 has a problem going on a distant journey. During short or town drives, it is fine.

When it turns to be a long journey, the car turns off after a while.

My mechanic tried a number of electrical fixes, but the problem persists.

He then decided to install a new ECU so he bought a new ECU FULL SET and installed. After installation, when he turns the key, the key/padlock light which is supposed to go off stays and blinks.
When he presses the breaks during idling, there's a vibration.

When he puts the old ECU on these signs stop.

Please advise.

Comment: We need a bit more info: 1) is this a new problem? 2) any recent repairs before the issue started? 3) have you owned the car since new? 4) mileage? 5) How long is a "long journey" 6) Are your "check engine", "service engine soon", or any other trouble lights on? 7) Is your temperature gauge reading normal?

Comment: 8) Can you turn it back on normally after it shuts down by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your concern.

Below are my answers.

-We initially suspected the engine so we changed the engine but transferred the old ECU to the newly installed engine. And since the issue persisted we decided to change the ECU too as the last resort.

Upon contacting the seller of the ECU, this is what he said

''Hi

yes i know it  , i was tell you this is not complete set.

Missing speedometer and bsi box

Now you have to reprogram the controller to the car  Using tech-2device  from the Opel

Thanks And Best Regards
Paweł Koch
www.auto24parts.com''

Other answers below:

-The last time it stopped, we had to tow the vehicle back to town as it could not start.
-Long journey means 120km+
-Vehicle had an excellent service record.

Thanks.

Gabriel